# CSS Grid dynamic header

Tags: css

I have about 50 rows:

```
<head>
<rows>
<rows>
<rows>
<rows>
...
```

Depending on the screen size I show

```
<Header>
<row> <row>
<row> <row>
<row> <row>
```

with:

```css
display:grid;
repeat(auto-fit, minmax(249px, 500px) );
```

But I would like to have for big screens (or even three columns):

```
<Head> <Head>
<row> <row>
<row> <row>
<row> <row>
```

and for small screens.

```
<head>
<rows>
<rows>
<rows>
<rows>
...
```

without implementing it twice.

is there any possibility with CSS Grid to show two headers if two columns are rendered

I'm using Angular.

Comment: Assuming you want a two-column layout for bigger screens and single column for smaller ones, it might be a matter of media query tweaks. E.g. you could `display: none;` for one of the heading column in a bigger viewport and keep the body rows 2 columns, while `display: block` the headings in smaller viewport and turn the body rows 1 column only.

Comment: I Just update the post. Actually I need a dynamic number of columns.

Comment: Does item 2 should arrive below the item 1 or all second column items should arrived below first column ? Because it does not seem clear just with your `row` item

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to create an element with CSS, and a html code is static.
The only solution would be using javascript to create a child div of your title.
Here I recommend you to use JQuery since it can react to window size modification. (don't forget to import JQuery in the header)

A first solution would be placing "manually" elements in the grid, and allocate the place of the first row to headers.

The second is what I prefer: create a first grid to place headers dynamically with JS and a second grid to store the results automatically.

Here I wrote a working example of what you want :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #head_cont{
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 800px;
            display:grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 300px) );
        }

        .header{
            width: 200px;
            height: 30px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .container{
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 800px;
            display:grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 300px) );
        }
        .item{
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: bisque;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }


        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="head_cont">
        <!-- <div class="header">im a title</div> -->
        <!-- <div class="header">create the title in js</div> -->
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
    </div>
</body>

<script >
    const get_grid_col = (cont_name) =>{
        let getStyle = window.getComputedStyle(cont_name);
        let nGridCol = getStyle.getPropertyValue("grid-template-columns").split(" ").length;
        return nGridCol;
    }    

    const modify_header = () => {
        let head_container = document.getElementById("head_cont");
        let nGridCol = get_grid_col(head_container)
        // console.log("nb grid col ", nGridCol)
        
        let nb_child = head_container.childElementCount;
        while (nb_child < nGridCol){
            let headerDiv = document.createElement("div");
            headerDiv.className = "header"
            // type div text here
            headerDiv.innerHTML = "Title created with Jquery";

            head_container.appendChild(headerDiv);
            nb_child = head_container.childElementCount;
        }
        if (nb_child > nGridCol){
            head_container.removeChild(head_container.lastElementChild);
        }

    }

    // for the first render
    let nCol = get_grid_col(document.getElementById("head_cont"))
    modify_header()

    
    // on window resize
    $(window).resize(() =>{
        modify_header()
    });

</script>
</html>
```